# Getting value of some elemnets by having their difference

Tags: math

I am currently working on particular algorithm, but I face with a problem that I'm not sure what I have to do to resolve it. I appreciate if anyone helps me out.

There are some `objects{O1,O2,O3,.....}`, each of them has a value that we don't know about its amount, we call them `{V1,V2,V3,....}` also there is another element we call it `w(w1,w2,w3.....)` which shows the difference between values, I mean `w1=v2-v1, w2=v3-v2,w3=v4-v3` and so on. I'm wondering if there is any way to get value of `v1,v2,v3...etc` without having the value of `V1`?

Looking forward for your reply guys,
Thanks.

Comment: If you're working on it, then you can post the code you have so far, so there is something concrete to discuss. At present this seems quite vague.

Comment: No, of course not. Knowing the differences between successive numbers in a list of numbers under-determines the set of numbers. This is particularly obvious in the case when `w1 = w2 = w3 = ... = wk = 1`. That would tell you that the `vi` are consecutive numbers, but nothing else could be inferred. You wouldn't be able to distinguish 3,4,5,6,7 from 10,11,12,13,14 (for example). Having said that, it would of course be possible if you know one of the numbers, and the known number wouldn't need to be the first one.

Comment: @JohnColeman could post this as an answer.

Comment: @Banana done -- with something else I thought of since that comment

Answer (score 2):

Not in general. Knowing the differences between successive numbers in a list of numbers under-determines the set of numbers. This is particularly obvious in the case when `w1 = w2 = w3 = ... = wk = 1`. That would tell you that the `vi`are consecutive numbers, but nothing else could be inferred. You wouldn't be able to distinguish `3,4,5,6,7` from `10,11,12,13,14` (for example).

Having said that, it would of course be possible if you know one of the numbers, and the known number wouldn't need to be the first one. Knowing any single one of the numbers would suffice. Furthermore, knowing something like the sum of the `vi` would be sufficient since you could express the sum as a function of the unknown number `v1` and solve the resulting equation.

Comment: well, thanks everyone. Actually, I didn't want to get a constant value for V1, but looks  I have to. Anyway, thanks